# Using preg_match_all to return part of image's url in Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url, preg-match-all

I'm trying to modify the function below so it returns the post first image url without the `http://`, the domain url and the backslash at the end, but I don't really know how to deal with regex in this case. I'm working in Wordpress by the way.

This is what the function returns:
`http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/image.jpg`

This is what I need:
`wp-content/uploads/2014/09/image.jpg`

```
function catch_first_image()
{
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all( '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches );
    $first_img = $matches[1][0];

    echo $first_img;
}
```

And a further explanation on the right regex will be very much appreciated :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pleas check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/8kKyDR)**

```
$output = preg_match_all( "/<img.*https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/([^\"']+)[\"'].*/i", $post->post_content, $matches );

echo $matches[1][0];
```

Explanation:

```
.* => any character zero or more times
https? => http or https
[^\/]+ => any character other than / at least one time
[\"'] => double or single quote
```

Comment: +1 for being less lazy than me. I would make the `.*` lazy (in fact, you don't even need the last one if you removed the trailing `>`) and **use a different delimiter** (in bold because you currently aren't escaping all `/`s).

Comment: Thanks for such a swift response! :) There's only one little detail. The way the function is written now is returning not only the part of the image's URL that I asked for, but also everything that goes after that, including properties like `alt`, `width` and `height`. It should end up right after the image format and before the closing double-quotes.

But that's also my fault, I should've clarified that before.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Amir! :) Now it works perfectly! I really need to learn how to deal with this. It seems to be something quite important in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression:

```
~<img.+?src=['"]http://www\.domain\.com/([^'"]+)['"].*?>~i
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/kS6fK0/1)

I just literally matched `http://www.domain.com` outside of your first capture group you reference. Note that I changed delimiters to `~` so we don't need to escape slashes. You may want to change this to `https?://(?:www\.)?` to make things more flexible. Don't forget to escape periods. Also, I made your dot-match-all repetitions lazy to save you from headaches in the future (`.+?` and `.*?`).

Comment: I'm not really sure about how regexes work, but Wordpress keeps on considering the `~` symbols as PHP errors. I might be doing something wrong while insert the code in my functions.php file :(

Comment: Expressions need ["delimiters"](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to say when an expression starts and ends..any modifiers (`i` for case-insensitive) goes after the ending delimiter. I used `~` so you didn't need to escape each `/` in the expression. Remember, this string still needs to be in quotes: `preg_match_all('~<img.+?src=[\'"]http://www\.domain\.com/([^\'"]+)[\'"].*?>~i', $post->post_content, $matches);`

Comment: Yeap, that's how I used it, but it doesn't return anything :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<img.+?https?://[^\/]+\/\K[^\"']+
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/194292)